# Bonsai identification and pruning tips

Tags: identification, pruning, bonsai

I purchased my first bonsai about 4 years ago but haven't taken regular care of it, mainly just watering it occasionally in the summer and rarely during the other months. I've been too afraid to trim it. During the last few months I've kept it by the window and watered it regularly and it began growing much more rapidly than in the past.

First question is, can anyone identify the type of tree?

Second, any tips on where and how far down to trim? The tallest branch is beginning to fall over from its own weight. I've watched a bunch of bonsai trimming videos on youtube, but the trees they trim are in much better shape than this.

Thanks!

[image: bonsai]
[image: bonsai]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is a type of [jade plant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jade_plant).

I want to preface my advice by saying that bonsai die, it's what they do best and if you want your plant to look like a bonsai you are going to need to prune it hard which may kill your plant.

If it were my personal plant, I would cut that thing right down so that each branch only had an inch still remaining so that I would get nice compact growth. Making each cut just above a node where new growth can occur. I would then put it closer to a light source because this plant is growing long and thin because it is reaching for light.

If you are less brave, I suggest you pick one branch and then prune that back and then see the result and then replicate it next year on the other branches if you are happy with the result.

For the timid: cut the branch back so that there are at least one set of leaves on the branch and wait until next sprouting season for when a lower branch or lower leaves grow and each growing season cut back to the lowest set of leaves until you get your desired result.